# Extension for photo gallery and slider

Tags: module, admin, media

I've looked at a few extensions out there but most are overkill or don't quite fit.

Keen to create a simple extension instead if someone wants to point the way.

- Admin interface to easily add photos with title, caption, description
- Page to display the gallery
- Block to show a set number of images and slide through them (eg, 3 shown, 12 total, slide transition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the module you described is not so simple at all as it may seem :) Not even considering the fact that nothing in Magento is simple ;) But if you like, you could, for example, start here: [how to create custom extension for Magento](http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-developper-guide-howto-tutorial-5).

Comment: thanks (can't upvote yet), I'll look into doing it myself.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: Paid Module**

I have had great success with a module called **Promo Banner Slider** on Magento Connect made by a company called Involic. Many large Magento stores are using this for their home page hero graphics.

At $39.99 it's fairly inexpensive.

*On Magento Connect:*

<strike>http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/promo-banner-slider-carousel-promoslider.html</strike>

*Direct Link*

<strike>http://involic.com/magento-extensions/magento-promo-slider.html</strike>

To add to any page, add the widget in the CMS.

**Option 2: DIY**

If you want to DIY this, you can easily use the carousel from Twitter Bootstrap -

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

Here's a tutorial on how to roll it into a page:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/twitter-bootstrap-101-the-carousel/

To add to any page, use the above tutorial to add the correct markup to the page in the CMS that you desire to display the images on.

Comment: Thanks, but not looking for a single image slider. Need a way to add photos with titles (and possibly descriptions) via admin and display multiple photos at a time with transitions.

Comment: Hello some of your url not working please update your answers for those url

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [Altima Lookbook](http://shop.altima.net.au/altima-lookbook-professional.html) ($85) where you can have a bit more than just slider - there you can place multiple clickable tags per slide e.g. one tag on dress and one tag on shoes of the model.

If you are on budget you can check [free](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/altima-lookbook-free-12884.html) version (with limited number of slides)